# How to calculate the average number of points randomly distributed within a time interval that are t + dt apart from one another?

Tags: probability, statistics

There are about $3\ 10^5$ points distributed randomly throughout 3 days, and I am trying to compute a histogram of the time delays between the points less than 40 microseconds apart.  Clearly, it is a flat distribution in time, but I am struggling with how to compute how many pairs of points should land in each time bin.  (For context, this is to compute a coincidence background for a physics experiment).

I tried to think of it as a Poisson distribution, but ran into trouble when I realized that there were infinitely many time intervals to consider.

I also tried modeling it like the birthday problem and got:

$P(k > x) = 1 - \frac{n!}{(n-m+x)!n^(m-x)}$

k is pairs of points in a bin, n is the number of 40microsec time intervals in 3 days, and m is the number of points

$P(k=x) = P(k > x-1)-P(k > x) = \frac{n!(m-x)}{(n-m+x)! n^{m-x+1}}$

But Mathematica gave me zero when I tried to calculate the average as $\Sigma xP(x)$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If we choose one point in particular and ignore end effects, the chance another given point is within $dt$ seconds after it is $\frac {dt}{3\cdot 24 \cdot 60 \cdot 60}=\frac {dt}{259200}$.  There are $\frac 12(3\cdot 10^5)^2$ pairs of points so you should expect to have $\frac {40 \cdot 10^{-6}}{259200}\cdot \frac 12(3\cdot 10^5)^2=\frac {125}{18}\approx 7 $ pairs within that span.  Since the chance of more than two points within your $40$ microseconds is small, the intervals within $40$ microseconds should be evenly distributed.

Comment: The linearity of expectation says the calculation of the expected number is correct.  It does not require independence.  Once you have the chance one pair is within $40$ microseconds you can multiply by the number of pairs to get the expected number of pairs with the time.  If you had three within one interval that would count as three pairs, but as there are few pairs within 40 the chance of three is very low.